# iOS views like in Facebook app

Tags: ios, view

I want to implement the menu that resides beneath the main application view:

http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/107/Purple/eb/62/0a/mzl.csgudeqz.320x480-75.jpg

I want to make it exactly as it is done in Facebook app.

The problem is that I don't know how to show two views on screen simultaneously: one with menu and one with main app screen.

How can I implement such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but if someone still looking for Facebook UI, here is an exact clone for Facebook iOS app, with sliding panels

https://github.com/gresrun/GHSidebarNav

Here is one more similar control

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`PSStackedView`](https://github.com/steipete/PSStackedView) on github. It's not perfect, but works fairly well and acts just like Facebooks stacked view.

Answer (score 0):

this is simple

Create a View Controller for menu( for ex MenuViewController).

> CGRect currentframe = self.view.frame;
>
> ```
> if (currentframe.origin.x < 0) {
>
>     destination.origin.x = 0;
>
> } else {
>     [self.view.superview addSubview:menuViewController.view];
>
>     [menuViewController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];
>
>     [self.view.superview sendSubviewToBack:menuViewController.view];
>
>     currentframe.origin.x -= 300;
> }
>
> [UIView animateWithDuration:0.10 animations:^{
>
>     self.view.frame = currentframe;   
>
>
> } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
>
>     if (currentframe.origin.x == 0) {
>
>       [menuViewController.view removeFromSuperview]; 
>
>     }
>
>
> }];
> ```

Hope it will work